# Sistema de curtida com Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, mariadb, innodb

Estou tentando fazer um stored procedure para um sistema simples de curtida, minha tabela está organizada assim:

- Curtidas
  - id **INT(11) - Auto Incremento**
  - post **INT(11) - chave estrangeira  (id - post)**
  - user **INT(11) - chave estrangeira (id - usuários)**

- Usuários
  - id **INT(11) - Auto Incremento**
  - nome **VARCHAR(15)**

- Post
  - id **INT(11) - Auto Incremento**
  - conteúdo **VARCHAR(200)**

Minha logica que estou tentando aplicar:

- @valor: 1 = curtiu, 2 = não curtiu
- @post: id do post
- @user: id do usuário

1.Se não existir um valor que corresponde igual ao id do usuário e ao id post ele cria um e acrescenta no tipo o valor.

2.Se existir e o tipo for igual ao valor enviado ele deleta.

3.Se existir e o tipo for diferente do valor, ele atualiza.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Teste`(
    IN `@valor` INT,
    IN `@post` INT,
    IN `@user` INT
)
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM curtida WHERE user = `@user` AND  post = `@post`)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO curtida (tipo, post, user) VALUES (`@valor`, `@post`, `@user`);
    END
ELSE    
    IF (SELECT tipo FROM curtida WHERE user = `@user` AND post = `@post`) = `@valor`
        BEGIN
            DELETE FROM curtida WHERE user = `@user` AND post = `@post`;
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            UPDATE FROM curtida SET tipo = `@valor` WHERE user = `@user` AND post = `@post`;
        END
```

Em todos os IF e END estão apresentando erro de sintaxe e eu já estou um pouco perdido com isso kkk, eu tá poderia fazer em php mas seria uma grande perda de desempenho pois iria usar varias queries e comparações

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O principal erro seria os `BEGIN` e `END` que estava usando nos `IF`.

Você pode ver a documentação [aqui](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/if/).

Como ficou:

```
 DELIMITER $$
 CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Teste`(IN `@valor` INT, IN `@post`  INT,IN `@user`  INT)
 BEGIN
     IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM curtida WHERE user = `@user` AND post = `@post`) THEN
         INSERT INTO curtida (tipo, post, user) VALUES (`@valor`, `@post`, `@user`);
     ELSEIF ((SELECT tipo FROM curtida WHERE user = `@user` AND post = `@post`) = `@valor`) THEN
             DELETE FROM curtida WHERE user = `@user` AND post = `@post`;
     ELSE
         UPDATE curtida SET tipo = `@valor` WHERE user = `@user` AND post = `@post`;
     END IF;
 END $$
 DELIMITER ;
```